# SharePoint: Modifying metadata in a Document Library, changes the file-modified date

Tags: sharepoint, metadata

We are using SharePoint 365.

In a Document Library, when we change the metadata (Properties), the date-modified in Windows Explorer (OneDrive-connected to SharePoint) will change.

In my mind, metadata is a layer on top of the document, and hence changes in metadata should NOT change the modified data of the file.

Is my logic totally wrong ??

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It is normal.

“Metadata” is the term used to describe additional data that gives information about your files. Metadata that you may already be familiar with includes “Created Date”, “Modified By”, “File Size”, “File Type”, etc. Also "Date modified" (called "Modified" in a SharePoint library) is metadata, which will be changed automatically when other metadata is changed.

Comment: While normal it's not ideal if you're using the Modified Date for retention.  What you hope to capture is how well kept/utilized the content is based on how often it's updated.  But when someone touches the metadata it can give the appearance the content was updated.  This necessitates another field (e.g. Revision Date) which must now be manually kept in order to distinguish between content and metadata updates.